# Ionide-fsharp for Visual Studio Code

Tags: f#, installation, intellisense, visual-studio-code, ionide

After I have installed Ionide for Visual Studio Code, how do I begin using it (eg. syntax highlighting, autocompletion)? What settings do I have to change?

Comment: I would suggest that you remove the `paket` tag and create a new tag for `Ionide`. I have never used Ionide, but from [this](http://ionide.io/) page under `Need Help?` it looks like those people *don't hang out here* at StackOverflow. I would suggest contacting them where they do hang out.

Comment: @GuyCoder Okay thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to change anything. It just works. The only issue I found is that I had to add the fsi path to the PATH environment variable in order to have fsi up and running.